# DocumentDB Permissions on Collections

Tags: collections, user-permissions, azure-cosmosdb

In my design I want to use DocumentDB as a back-end for my multi tenant SAAS application.
As the data per tenant can be > 10gb I want to use a collection per tenant model. 
The requirement is how can I ensure data isolation in my application. Tenant 1 should not be able to see tenant 2 data in code and on azure portal. How can I set permissions on collections for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to use a collection per tenant model

You could try to [create DocumentDB users for each tenant and associate the permissions with the user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-secure-access-to-data) to control user access to collection/documents.

```
string documentCollectionlink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("{database id}", "{collection id}").ToString();

string databaseLink = UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("{database id}").ToString();

Permission docPermission = new Permission
{
    PermissionMode = PermissionMode.All,
    ResourceLink = documentCollectionlink,
    Id = "tenant1perm"
};

await client.CreateUserAsync(databaseLink, new User { Id = "tuser" });

docPermission = await client.CreatePermissionAsync(UriFactory.CreateUserUri("{database id}", "tuser"), docPermission);
```

and then you could read permissions for DocumentDB  user and get access token based on the tenant, and create a new instance of the DocumentClient with the token to operate the resource.

```
var qclient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUri), token);
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped. Can I also have a group of users or a role based permission on collections?

Comment: As far as I know, there are no **groups** and **roles** concept in Azure DocumentDB. As I mentioned in my reply, for implementing **multi-tenancy** in your application, you could create users in DocumentDB which corresponds to your actual users or the tenants of your application. Please check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-resources#users) to know more about DocumentDB user.

Comment: Any updates? If the reply help you solve the problem, please mark it as answer, which will help others quickly find the answer and solve similar issues.

Comment: Thanks for your update.  Users or roles will have to be created in DocumentDB. For collections we cannot create users and persist that information. But can form queries by reading user and permission information from same collection which have documents containing users and permissions and creating queries for actual data with User and Permission classes.